# Make use of trigonometric identities to get the value of all 6 trigonometric functions of 165 degrees

Tags: trigonometry

Use trigonometric identities to get the value of all 6 trigonometric functions of 165 degrees.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, some people on this site consider the use of imperatives (use, prove, explain etc.) rude. Consider editing you question

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $165=(180-30)+(30/2)$. $\ \ \ \ \ \!\!\!\!$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: $165=120+45$. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Using [All Sin Tan Cos](http://www.knightswoodsecondary.org.uk/personal/Resources/Worksheets/trig5.pdf) formula,

$\sin(180^\circ-x)=\sin x,\cos(180^\circ-x)=-\cos x$  and $\tan(180^\circ-x)=-\tan x$

and $\sin(A-B)=\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B,$

$\cos(A-B)=\cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B$

and $\tan(A-B)=\frac{\tan A-\tan B}{1+\tan Atan B}$

$\sin(165^\circ)=\sin(180^\circ-15^\circ)=\sin 15^\circ=\sin(60^\circ-45^\circ)$

$\cos(165^\circ)=\cos(180^\circ-15^\circ)=-\cos 15^\circ=-\cos(60^\circ-45^\circ)$

$\tan(165^\circ)=\tan(180^\circ-15^\circ)=-\tan 15^\circ=-\tan(60^\circ-45^\circ)$

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this for $15^\circ$. Once you get the value for the sine, the rest can be readily obtained.  Use the fact that $45 - 30 = 15$.